# JS Object being logged as HTML Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, grails

I am working on a javascript control for work, and integrating it into a grails plugin. All the plugin simply does is populate the options based on a taglib, which looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var ${name} = $("#${name}").tagInput({
    $inputListener: $("#${inputListenerName}"),
    $errorHandler: $("#${errorHandler}"),
    $domainListener: $("#${domainListenerName}"),
    errorClass: "${errorClass}",
    validClass: "${validClass}",
    caseSensitive: ${caseSensitive},
    constraints: {
        minSize: ${minSize},
        maxSize: ${maxSize},
        maxTags: ${maxTags},
        validationRegex: "${tagRegex}"
    },
    errorMessages: {
        size: "${sizeErrorMessage}",
        regex: "${regexErrorMessage}",
        maxTags: "${maxTagsError}"
    },
    responsive: {
        length: ${maxTagLength},
        lengthxs: ${maxTagLengthxs},
        xsMode: ${xsWidth}
    }
});
debugger;
});
```

Which looks like this when evaluated:

```
var emailTags = $("#emailTags").tagInput({
    $inputListener: $("#invitesInput"),
    $errorHandler: $("#inviteErrors"),
    $domainListener: $("#null"),
    errorClass: "label-danger",
    validClass: "label-primary",
    caseSensitive: false,
    constraints: {
        minSize: 1,
        maxSize: 255,
        maxTags: 100,
        validationRegex: "[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+"
    },
    errorMessages: {
        size: "",
        regex: "Must be a valid email string.",
        maxTags: "You have entered too many recipients. Please send out invites before adding more recipients."
    },
    responsive: {
        length: 50,
        lengthxs: 20,
        xsMode: 768
    }
});
```

When Chrome hits the debugger statement, I have the correct object. Which is:

```
tagInput {parseTags: function, clear: function, serialize: function}
```

If I step out of this, I immediately entry jQuery and my object is instantly turned into

```
div#emailTags.turningTags
```

which eventually turns into

```
<div id=​"emailTags" name=​"emailTags" class=​"turningTags ">​…​</div>​
```

If it helps, here is the current code for the tagInput object.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e785ec24e0c1388cd599

Why is this happening? Why is my object being turned into this HTML element? I have tried changing the name of the variable to no avail, no matter what I change the name of this variable to, it happens every time. I have tried making it a standalone object and not a jQuery function and the same thing STILL keeps happening.

Comment: It would help if you showed us the ACTUAL generated javascript that the browser sees, not the template code so we can see what the browser is actually executing.  You can see that in View/Source in the browser.

Comment: My bad, wrote this up in an annoyed mood. Drove home and am messing with it some more. I updated the main post with the evaluated template!

Comment: So, what is the actual execution problem in your page? It sounds like you're just seeing the representation of something change in the debugger, but it isn't clear to us what the actual problem in your page/code is? If your question is fully about what you see in the debugger, then you will have to be a lot more clear about exactly what you're looking at in the debugger when it's on what line of source code.

Comment: I ended up changing some functionality and the issue went away. I have no idea what the cause was.